# Cordova, Infinite Loop redirection with ionic framework

Tags: cordova, loops, routes, ionic-framework

I'm developing an wp8 application with ionic and I have a problem with the ionic routes. The problem is that i have an inifinite loop redirection.  Here is my code!

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider
.state('tab', {
url: '/tab',
abstract: true,
templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
});
$stateProvider.state('tab.dash', {
        url: '/dash',
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
    });
    $stateProvider.state('install', {
        url: '/install',
        templateUrl: 'templates/install/first.html',
        controller: 'install'
    });

  $stateProvider.state('userview', {
      url: '/users/:id',
      params: { id: null},
      templateUrl: 'templates/users/view.html',
      controller: 'viewUser'
  });

// The default route
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/install');

 });
```

And the "install" controller does not fire.

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
```

`.controller('install',function($scope){
    alert("Heho!");
})`
...

When i debug my app with the navigator, it works perfectly. It redirect to the install controller without loopping. But with my device, i have a infinite redirection.